# YouTube Content ID API returns Forbidden error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've created a service account for use with the YouTube Content ID API, I'm following the steps under Set up your service account on:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/oauth2_for_service_accounts

The steps seem to be a bit outdated, I am not able to find YouTube Content ID API in Developer console.

I  am able to upload a video on a channel.
Well, when I'm making requests using this service account, I'm getting forbidden errors. For example the below error is when I'm trying to get a list of content owners.

```
error::::::{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'));
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $youtubePartner = new Google_Service_YouTubePartner($client);
$contentOwnersListResponse = $youtubePartner->contentOwners->listContentOwners(
          array('fetchMine' => true));
          $contentOwnerId = $contentOwnersListResponse['items'][0]['id'];
```

Comment: You have mentioned that you cannot see the "YouTube Content ID API" in your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), I think you need to check the [YouTube Partner Program](https://www.youtube.com/partner). Please do take note that "**The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube content partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all YouTube users**". It was stated in the note at the top most of the [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/oauth2_for_service_accounts#top_of_page).

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you cannot see the "YouTube Content ID API" in your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), I think you need to check the [YouTube Partner Program](https://www.youtube.com/partner). Please do take note that "**The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by YouTube content partners and is not accessible to all developers or to all YouTube users**". It was stated in the note at the top most of the [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/oauth2_for_service_accounts#top_of_page).